# Brezis' exercise 8.25.2: prove that the bilinear form $a$ on $H^1 (I)$ is coercive

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, bilinear-form

Let $I$ be the open interval $(0, 2)$ and $V=H^1(I)$. Consider the bilinear form
$$
a(u, v) = \int_0^2 u'v' + \left(\int_0^1 u\right) \left(\int_0^1 v\right) .
$$

I'm trying to solve a problem in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Exercise 8.25**
>
> 1. Check that $a(u, v)$ is a continuous symmetric bilinear form, and that $a(u, u)=0$ implies $u=0$.
> 2. Prove that $a$ is [coercive](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Lax%E2%80%93Milgram_theorem#The_Lax%E2%80%93Milgram_theorem).
>    [**Hint:** Argue by contradiction and assume that there exists a sequence $\left(u_n\right)$ in $H^1(I)$ such that $a\left(u_n, u_n\right) \rightarrow 0$ and $\left\|u_n\right\|_{H^1}=1$. Let $\left(u_{n_k}\right)$ be a subsequence such that $u_{n_k}$ converges weakly in $H^1(I)$ and strongly in $L^2(I)$ to a limit $u$. Show that $u=0$.]

My below proof of (2.) is different from the suggested hint. Could you please check if I made some subtle mistakes?

---

We need an auxiliary result (in the same book)

> [Exercise 6.12](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4726063/brezis-exercise-6-12-a-lemma-of-j-l-lions) Let $X,Y,Z$ be real Banach spaces with corresponding norms $|\cdot|_X, |\cdot|_Y, |\cdot|_Z$. Assume that $X \subset Y$ with *compact* injection and that $Y \subset Z$ with *continuous* injection. Prove that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $C_\varepsilon > 0$ such that
> $$
> |u|_Y \le \varepsilon |u|_X + C_\varepsilon |u|_Z
> \quad \forall u \in X.
> $$

Let $X := H^1 (I), Y := L^2 (I)$ and $Z:=\mathbb R$. Then $X \to Y, u \mapsto u$ and $Y \to Z, u \mapsto \int_0^1 u$ are compact linear operators. Fix $\varepsilon \in (0, 1/2)$. By **Exercise 6.12**, there is $C_\varepsilon > 0$ such that
$$
\|u\|_{L^2} \le \varepsilon \|u\|_{H^1} + C_\varepsilon \left | \int_0^1 u \right |
\quad \forall u \in H^1(I),
$$
which implies
$$
\|u\|^2_{L^2} \le 2\varepsilon [ \|u'\|_{L^2}^2 + \|u\|_{L^2}^2] + 2C_\varepsilon^2 \left | \int_0^1 u \right |^2
\quad \forall u \in H^1(I),
$$
which implies
$$
(1-2\varepsilon) [\|u'\|^2_{L^2} + \|u\|^2_{L^2}] \le (2C_\varepsilon^2+1) \left ( \|u'\|_{L^2}^2 +  \left | \int_0^1 u \right |^2 \right )
\quad \forall u \in H^1(I),
$$
which implies
$$
(1-2\varepsilon) \|u\|^2_{H^1} \le (2C_\varepsilon^2+1) |a(u, u)|^2
\quad \forall u \in H^1(I).
$$

Comment: is correct. You could also prove the ex 6.12 with that hint.